# javascript works differently in deployed IE vs VS debugger, ff, chrome etc

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, visual-studio-2012

UPDATE:
I used the IE debug console, and it turns out "setSelectionRange" isn't valid in IE... why it works from Visual Studio, but not outside of it is beyond me, but basically the JS fails at that line, and never returns false... so now the question is: how can I code it differently so that IE will perform? I've tried to look for JQuery plugins, but haven't found one yet...

So I've got some validation done by some javascript, and some prefilling as well, for some textboxes in a gridview.  the code is supposed called from the onkeypress event.  It works just fine in debug mode... the characters are limited to numbers, and the y and m key presses auto populate/append the word years or months, and the curser is correctly positioned at the end of the numbers portion.  It also works in Chrome and FF.  However, most of our company runs on IE9 (and this problem also happens in IE10 on my pc.)  Once I deploy the aspx page, the IE users still get the character restrictions and autofill, but the characters y and m aren't suppressed, and the curser placement doesn't happen, so the curser is at the end of "9 Yearsy" or "6 Monthsm".  the javascript is listed below; I know that there are quirks behind javascript implementation, but why would it only be happening after I deploy the code.  And any suggestions on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated...

```
    var timeFrame = function (evt, txtbox, max) {
    if (evt.type != 'blur') {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31
                  && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
                    if (charCode == 121 || charCode == 109) {
                        if (charCode == 121) {
                            //fill with years
                            var entry = (txtbox.value);
                            var words = entry.split(' ');
                            if (max) {
                                txtbox.value = 'Maximum '.concat(words[1], ' Years');
                                txtbox.setSelectionRange(8 + words[1].length, 8 + words[1].length);
                                return false;
                            } else {
                                txtbox.value = words[0].concat(' Years');
                                txtbox.setSelectionRange(words[0].length, words[0].length);
                                return false;
                            }

                        }
                        if (charCode == 109) {
                            //fill with months
                            var entry = (txtbox.value);
                            var words = entry.split(' ');
                            if (max) {
                                txtbox.value = 'Maximum '.concat(words[1], ' Months');
                                txtbox.setSelectionRange(8 + words[1].length, 8 + words[1].length);
                                return false;
                            } else {
                                txtbox.value = words[0].concat(' Months');
                                txtbox.setSelectionRange(words[0].length, words[0].length);
                                return false;
                            }

                        }
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                var str = txtbox.value;
                if (str != '') {
                    if (charCode == 46 && str.indexOf('.') !== -1) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (max) {
                        if (txtbox.value.indexOf('Maximum') == -1) {
                            txtbox.value = 'Maximum '.concat(str);
                            str = txtbox.value;
                        }

                        var words = str.split(' ');
                        if (isNaN(parseInt(words[1]))) {
                            txtbox.value = '';
                        } else {
                            txtbox.setSelectionRange(8 + words[1].length, 8 + words[1].length);
                        }
                    } else {
                        var words = str.split(' ');
                        if (isNaN(parseInt(words[0]))) {
                            txtbox.value = '';
                        } else {
                            txtbox.setSelectionRange(words[0].length, words[0].length);
                        }
                    }


                }
                return true;

            }
        }
<asp:TextBox ID="TermTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Term") %>' onKeyPress="return timeFrame(event, this, false);" onKeyUp="timeFrame(event, this, false);" onblur="timeFrame(event, this, false);"  MaxLength="25" Width="200px" />
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript Console? By the way, this is one of the reasons that libraries like jQuery exist - browsers have never been JavaScript compatible.

Comment: No, VS isn't showing any errors, and like I said, it works in FF, so using firebug doesn't show me anything going wrong either :/

Comment: What about errors in the IE9/10 Console itself? There may be other factors (IE compatibility mode or other JavaScript code for example) that cause the deployed page running in IE to behave differently.

Comment: It [**is supported**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Input.setSelectionRange#Browser_compatibility) in `IE9+`. Is the page being rendered in compatibility mode? Press `F12` to get the IE console up and see the "Browser Mode" and "Document Mode". Anything other than IE9 and IE9 (for IE9 browser) will probably be the reason it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after what andyb said, I dug into why setSelectionRange was failing... turns out in IE, there's compatibility mode and document mode... and while our compatibility mode was running ie9, the document mode was defaulting to id7 standards.  so I added the following meta tag to the head of the asp doc...

```
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

...and now IE recognized the command, and everything works perfect.

Comment: Great! I thought it would be something like that. You can "accept" your own answer if you want :)

Answer (score 0):

It is just a guess, but I think you can try to check deployed source code whether your javascript code wasn`t minified. Your *timeFrame* method could be shortened to something like *x* or *y*, but your onKeyUp method still contains non-shortened name *timeFrame*.